# C++ HTTP requests API

Tags: c++, http, httprequest

I'm rewriting a Java project in C++ where I used [okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/). Is there a similar lib to easily send GET/POST requests? I tried to setup cURLpp but can't find a guide to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [cpp-netlib](https://cpp-netlib.org/index.html) based on C++11